# error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Dog' to data type int The error is on the line 40

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create dynamic SQL statement, but I'm getting following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Dog' to data type
>   int The error is on the line 40

What does this error actually means and where is this error in my StoredProcedure

```
USE exercise

GO

CREATE PROC REPORT

@customerID VARCHAR
AS

SELECT * INTO #temp FROM customer,animal WHERE customer.customerID = @customerID

ALTER TABLE #temp

ADD

Printed SMALLINT

UPDATE #temp

SET Printed = 0

DECLARE @customerName VARCHAR (30)
DECLARE @customerTelephone VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @animalID INT
DECLARE @animalName VARCHAR (30)
DECLARE @quantity INT
DECLARE @price INT
DECLARE @speciesName VARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @totalPrice INT

SELECT  
        @customerName = customer.customerName,

        @customerTelephone = customer.customerTelephone

        FROM customer 

        WHERE @customerID = customer.customerID

        PRINT 'CustomerID: ' +@customerID
        PRINT 'Customer Name ' +@customerName
        PRINT 'Customer Telephone: ' +@customerTelephone
        PRINT'animalID  animalName  quantity  price  Species  totalPrice'
        WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE Printed = 0)
        BEGIN
        SELECT @animalID = MIN(animalID) FROM #temp WHERE Printed = 0

        SELECT @animalName = animalName,
                @quantity = animalCustomer.quantity,
                @speciesName = species.specieName
                FROM animal
                 INNER JOIN animalCustomer ON animal.animalID = animalCustomer.animalIdentificater 
                INNER JOIN species ON species.specieName = animal.speciesIdentificater
                WHERE animal.animalID = @animalID
                SET @totalPrice = @price * @quantity            
                PRINT @animalID+'  '+@animalName+'  '+@quantity+'  '+@speciesName+'  '+@totalPrice          
        UPDATE #temp
                SET Printed = 1
                WHERE @animalID = animalID
        END


DROP TABLE #temp
GO
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error usually means that you are using the `+` sign for string concatenation.  But one or more of the variables is numeric (in this case an integer).

By my reckoning, this is line 40:

```
    PRINT 'CustomerID: ' +@customerID
```

You might try someting like:

```
    PRINT 'CustomerID: ' + cast(@customerID as varchar(255))
```

You'll probably have this problem on other lines in your code as well.  Good luck.

Comment: No My CustomerID Prints just Fine

Comment: @user2217550 . . . Then it is in another, similar line.  You know what line 40 is in your code.  That is line 40 in the code you posted.  The idea is the same, regardless.  You are using `+` with the intention of conatenation, but one or more of the arguments is an integer.